# Installing netbeans for ubuntu using synaptic manager/terminal

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

I have installed netbeans in ubuntu through synaptic manager without any problem, but when I started using it and tried to create a "web application" in java, I found that there is no option for creating web applications.

I followed following steps after installing it:
File --> New project --> new tab opened with no option for web applications.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and installed netbeans 7.0.1

I have also tried to install netbeans through terminal, but there also faced the same problem, no option for developing/creating web application in java.

Please someone help me to know where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install some plugins. Open "Tools>Plugins>Settings" menu.
Select the "Certified Plugins" server, then click the "Reload Catalog" button under "Available Plugins" tab.
Finally, check "Java Web Applications" and click the "Install" button.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me under Netbeans Distributions along with Certified Plugins.

Comment: Still not working, though I have installed plugin for GlassFish server "GlassFish v1, v2.x", while creating web application in step 3 "Server and setting" there is blank drop down list opposite to server option, when I tried to Add it(using Add button near to the drop down list), they are asking to download it now, which results in either "Badly formed URL: null" or "I/O Exception: Invalid Http response".

Comment: It was a [known bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228259), fixed on NetBeans 7.3.1. Try to download and install GlassFish yourself.